# Every time I open a csv OpenOffice Calc resets cell formating

Tags: openoffice-calc

I am using OpenOffice Calc to view and change a particular csv. This csv has some numbers that start with 0 and some dates. I need to have both the numbers and the dates in a Text cell format. When I specify this cell format, close the file and reopen it, the cell format is back to default. As a result the dates are cut and the 0 disappears.

I can't put an apostrophe in front of the numbers because I am passing the csv to a python script and the apostrophe causes problems.

I tried the solution from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/328112/permanently-and-globally-stop-openoffice-calc-from-autocorrecting-dates-time) but it doesn't seem to apply the new template

How can I make OpenOffice Calc remember my choices?

Thank you all!

Comment: "I am passing the csv to a python script and the apostrophe causes problems." so fix the python script.

Comment: @DavidPostill , unfortunately it is not an option. In case you down voted the post, could you explain why? I really want to learn following the regulations, I am new user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV format doesn't support such formatting choices you want OpenOffice to remember. Either you have to use another format like .xlsx or .ods or use the apostrophe trick.

Both solutions will require you to change in some ways the python script.

If you choose to use the string format for the data, you'll have to make the script interpret the data correctly. If you choose the .xls or .ods way, you could use pandas to open the spreadsheets in python.